# Jenkinsfile shared params in source control

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to jenkins and inherited a bunch of declarative pipelines of unknown code quality. Each pipeline uses folder properties to set shared default param values. This puts essential variables outside of source control, which kills our PR process and our history for debugging. For example

```
    //pipelineA/Jenkinsfile
    pipeline {
        parameters {
            string name: 'important_variable', defaultValue: folderProperty('important_variable')
        }
        //etc
    }

    //pipelineB/Jenkinsfile
    pipeline {
        parameters {
            string name: 'important_variable', defaultValue: folderProperty('important_variable')
        }
        //etc
    }
```

Then in the root folder a property `important_variable` is set to `"Hello World"`

Is there a way to get this into source control either by setting the folder property to extract the variable from a yaml, or by using shared libraries?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone reads this, we ended up:

1. Create a `bootstrap.groovy` file
2. This file MUST go in a `/vars` directory at the absolute top of your repo
3. Using the Jenkins UI we went to the pipeline's parent directory > config and created a shared library called `config-lib` that points at our repo and automatically exposes the `bootstrap.groovy` file methods as long as the file is in the right place
4. The `bootstrap.groovy` file has a `call` method that returns a map with key value pairs for our default parameters. This method has to be named `call`
5. In the `Jenkinsfile` for the pipeline we include the following two lines:

```
@Library("config-lib") _
config = bootstrap()
```

- The library decorator *(note it ends with `_`)* imports the `config-lib` methods defined in the jenkins ui
- The bootstrap function calls the `call` method from the `bootstrap.groovy` file in that `config-lib` library

6. in the Jenkinsfile use the `config` map to populate the param default values

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        string name: 'foo', defaultValue: config.foo
    }
```

And it's done.

This video helped immensely: https://youtu.be/Wj-weFEsTb0